# Squid in reverse proxy mode: need to rewrite host headers

Tags: linux, reverse-proxy, squid

I am trying to deploy squid on a server to which I can point a number of domain names and have it load content from my main domain www.example.com, which is on my private network.

Basically I need a way to rewrite the host headers sent from the clients to www.example.com at all times, otherwise the backend server will not respond to unknown vhosts (cannot change this).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Have tried specifying defaultsite but that only works when there is no Host header sent by clients. Also tried

```
header_replace Host www.example.com
```

with no effect.

TIA